# Not able to set property values to Spring-web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I've a context listener where I'm loading all the properties. These properties I'm trying to set in my spring-web.xml, but it throws an exception

Because its not able to fetch and set the property to the xml

Here is my spring-web.xml

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:as400://localhost/BB" />
    <property name="username" value="{as400.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="{as400.password}" />
</bean>
```

My class of loading properties

```
public class LoadProperties implements ServletContextListener {

private static Properties properties = null;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoadProperties .class); 

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) { }

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    properties = BBUtil.getProperties("datasource-cfg.properties");
    for (String prop : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        logger.info("Property Loaded :"+properties.getProperty(prop));
        if (System.getProperty(prop) == null) {            
            System.setProperty(prop, properties.getProperty(prop));
        }
    }
}

}
```

This class is getting executed and setting the properties under System.

This is my properties file

```
as400.username=ROOT
as400.password=ROOT
```

How can I set the values into my spring-web.xml

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we load it using `context:property-placeholder`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties" />

<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="dbHost" value="${db.url}"/>    
        <property name="dbPort" value="${db.number}"/>
        <property name="dbService" value="${db.name}"/>
        <property name="dbUrl" value="${db.user}"/>
        <property name="dbPassword" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>
```

The properties file can also be loaded using prefixes such as http:,file:

The placeholder should be used with a $ sign as follows

```
<property name="username" value="${as400.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${as400.password}" />
```

ExtendedIllegalArgumentException essentially indicates that the argument passed is invalid.